# Compile lots of TeX files at the same time (or with a single command)

Tags: command-line, compiling, latex

I have hundreds of little `TikZ` graphs which I need to compile in order to include to my main document.

How could I compile them all with a single command? (not at the same time, which is not possible; but do want to avoid to `pdflatex`-them with single commands).

---

Comment: Are they in one `.tex` file, or in multiple?

Comment: `for i in ...; do pdflatex "$i"; done` Replace `...` with whatever is appropriate to select your files; the information you have given is not sufficient to do it for you.

Comment: @luchonacho No they're multiple files. Their names are not regular (like indexed by integers or sequences or nothing). // thanks, frakiem.

Comment: Can't you have a bunch of `\include{yourGraphXyz.tex}` in your document? To generate them for all files in a folder, try this shell command: `printf "\\include{%s}\n" yourGraph*.tex`

Comment: Agree with @Lekensteyn Check [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/79595/77895).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was just:

```
 for i in *.tex; do pdflatex "$i"; done
```